# Java: Array of Arrays from JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSON Arrays of Array like this

```
"results": [
    {
        "id": "AAA",
        "color": "#4D4837",
        "links": {
            "self": "https://aaa.com",
            "html": "https://bbb.com",
            "download": "https://ccc.com",
            "download_location": "ddd.com"
        },
        "categories": [],
        "likes": 3891,

     },
    {
        "id": "BBB",
        "color": "#4D453",
        "links": {
            "self": "https://abb.com",
            "html": "https://bcc.com",
            "download": "https://ccc.com",
            "download_location": "ddd.com"
        },
        "categories": [],
        "likes": 3000,

     }
 ]
```

And I would like to retrieve "https://bbb.com" and "https://bcc.com" of "html", but I don't know how to do that.

Based on kindly comment, I put the following. 
somehow, "getJSONObject()"can not be put. The error message says "Cannot resolve method 'getJSONObject' in 'JSONArray'".

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray((Collection) jobjt.get("Strings"));
        for (int i =0 ; i<2 ; i++){
            JSONObject job = (JSONObject) array.get(i);   --> get(i) can not be changed to getJSONObject(i)
            String id = job.get("id").toString();
            String color = job.get("color").toString();
            String photoUrl = job.get("links").toString();  --> By updating here, I want to store only "https://bbb.com" and "https://bcc.com".

        }
```

But when I tried to use the following, not only "html", but "self" and the other information are retrieved.

```
String photoUrl = job.get("links").toString();
```

Please tell me how to retrieve only "html".

I am using IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to be followed(assuming you have proper JSONArray you mentioned):

1. get JSONObject from your JSONArray by index ie. for your case, `index=0` here
2. Get the inner JSONObject by key of `links`
3. Now, access your content by key of `html`

Example for your case:

```
JSONObject indexedObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject linksObject = indexedObject.getJSONObject("links");
String html= linksObject.getString("html");
```

Better keep checking if key exists as Harshal suggests

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I might be wrong, but I can not see the "getJSONObject" from my IntelliJ. So how can I do that?

Comment: did your add any maven repo or jar/lib for handling JSONObject?

Comment: Yes, I added json-20190722.jar from "https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java". is that right approach?

Comment: that should work. it seems your jar is not added in your classpath. What do you get in suggestion when start typing JSON or like this?

Comment: I added that jar file and set from project structure - Modules - Dependencies Tab. And when I tried to put "getJSONObject", "Cannot resolve method 'getJSOMObject' in 'JSONArray" came up.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to work. However, try removing the jar and re-add it[see how to add in your IDE in google] and rerun the project.

Comment: I could do that. My jar does not have that. So I downloaded another jar and installed it. Thank you!